# Where was Herod's temple built?

Tags: history, israel, temple, archaeology

The Scripture says that the Second Temple was built on the foundation of Solomon's Temple, but was Herod's Temple built in the same place or was it built next to it? (Do we have any records that say so?)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Though this question isn't technically about Christianity, perhaps it will be considered on-topic here anyway, since the Temple is a significant site in the New Testament. We'll see what the mods think.

Comment: This appears to be the only forum in Stack Exchange where this question even remotely matches.

Comment: The other possibility, where this question *might* fit better, is [Judaism StackExchange](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/). It might be worth your while searching there to see if there is a similar question already there. If by "The Scripture" you are referring to anything in the New Testament, this question would have to be modified to fit well there. What, exactly, *do* you mean by "The Scripture"? What passages are you referring to? Passages in Ezra and Nehemiah? This might also clarify your question.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden, Thanks, after sitting here almost a week without any comments or answers, I moved it to the Judaism Stack Exchange and got two pages of answers in the first two hours.

Comment: The question on the Judaism site is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66517/where-was-herods-temple-built

Answer (score 1):

[image]Herod's Temple is the massive building on which the Salomon Temple (with golden roof) stood, so the chances are; however, there is no archeological evidence of any previous Salomon Temple.

http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/0c/b4/ca/0cb4ca76c5c01a5b43938663503a222e.jpg